# Equivalent characterizations of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

The definition we have for holomorphic functions is

> $f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic if it is is $C^1$ as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ and the Jacobian is a rotation-dilation.

I am struggling to see why this is equivalent to the fact that the limit of the difference quotient exists, mostly because of the $C^1$ condition. I know that if the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied AND the partials are continuous, then the function is complex differentiable. But doesn't the definition I have (the first sentence) say that this is also necessary -- that is, the partials *have* to be continuous?

Comment: You mean $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes. Recall that if $f$ is holomorphic then it is actually INFINITELY differentiable which easily implies that the real coordinate functions are $C^1$.

Answer (score 2):

Just a reminder, a function $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic provided $f$ is complex differentiable **AND** the derivative  $f'(z)$ **has to be continuous** (this is actually redundant due to Goursat's Theorem, nevertheless it simplifies the beginning of the theory) .

Comment: Just a comment: I think this is not how most people define holomorphic. As you point out, it's largely irrelevant since all end up being equivalent, but usually holomorphic just means complex differentiable.

Comment: @AlexYoucis The point of Goursat's theorem is to get rid of this requirement, but apriori you do need to assume continuity.

Comment: There is no assumption of continuity of $f^{\prime}$ in the definition of a holomorphic function.

Comment: @carmichael561 If you use a standard text such as John B. Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable, then you will see it's part of the definition. Here's the link https://emineter.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/conway-functions-of-one-complex-variable-2ed-1978lt167s.pdf