# 3D / nD version of "amplitwist" (Drehstreckung) property of holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, terminology, cauchy-riemann-equations

**Note:** *This question is probably a duplicate but difficult to Google, so please feel free to close and link to the original question if this is a duplicate.* **/Note**

> **Question 1:** Is there a term for functions with the following property?
>
> - Let $U, V$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f: U \to V$ be a continuously ([Frechet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)) differentiable function such that,
>   for each $u \in U$, the derivative $D f (u) = a(u) T(u)$ for some
>   functions $a: U \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $T: U \to SO(n)$.
>
>   - I.e. at every point in the domain of $f$, the derivative of $f$ is a linear transformation that is a composition of a rotation
>     ("twist", "Drehung") and multiplication by a nonnegative constant
>     ("amplification", "Streckung").

*In the case of $n=2$, with $\mathbb{R}^2$ interpreted as $\mathbb{C}$, this condition is supposed to be equivalent to satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations in an open region, and thus to being holomorphic. (Cf. e.g. *Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham.)*

> **Question 2:** If functions with this property do have a name including when $n > 2$, then is it known whether such functions still
> have any extra "nice" properties even in the case where $n > 2$? Or is
> $n=2$ special?

*For example in the case that $n=2$, the aforementioned textbook argues that this property can be used to prove Cauchy's formula for holomorphic functions and with it their infinite differentiability. Do any analogous results hold for $n > 2$?*

> **Bonus question:** Can the condition that $f$ is *continuously* differentiable be omitted, i.e. is it implied by the remaining
> conditions?

*I'm unclear on whether it can be omitted in the $n=2$ case, and hence even more so when $n > 2$.*

**Related questions:** Again this question is difficult to Google, but this question on MathOverflow might be related: [generalisation of Cauchy-Riemann equations to 3D](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96910/generalisation-of-cauchy-riemann-equations-to-3d)

In particular [one of the answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96919) states "a mapping has the title property in dimension at least three if and only if it is either constant or a Riemannian covering up to homothety. For $\mathbb{R}^n$ this means a composition of translations, rotations, and homothety ($x \to a x$, for some $a > 0$)".

Now I'm not sure whether the property asked about in that question (preserving harmonicity) is equivalent to the property above. (Honestly I don't think it is.) But the property above is requiring that the derivative at every point be the composition of a rotation and a homothety, so based on that answer it sounds like it could be related.

The reference used by this math.se question [Equivalent characterizations of holomorphic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944498/equivalent-characterizations-of-holomorphic-functions) appears to state the result in $n=2$ whose generalization I am asking about: "$f \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic if it is is $C^1$ as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ and the Jacobian is a rotation-dilation".

Also [one of the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944515/606791) to that question seems to the answer the bonus question in the case that $n=2$, namely that the extra hypothesis of continuous differentiability is unnecessary due to [Goursat's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Goursat+theorem).

Comment: The case $n=2$ is definitely special.  See the term "conformal" in English.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)